# Javascript(JQuery) || How i indexing attribute name from added row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a dynamic table. and I put a button to increase the number of rows in the table. then when I made the javascript code, attribute name in the textbox the javascript it is not indexed PHP. the question is how can I make the textbox can be indexed so that I can store data of the previous rows and the new rows?

```
function tambahact(){
  html = "<tr>"
    +"<td ondblclick='tambahact()'></td>"
    +"<td><input class='form-control' style='margin:10px; left:3px; width:90%;' name='activity[]'></td>"
    +"<td><select class='form-control' name='status[]'><option>Yes</option><option>No</option><option>Not Applicable</option></select></td>"
    +"<td><input type='text' name='value[]' class='form-control' autocomplete='off' value='' style='margin:10px; left:3px; width:90%;'></td>"
    +"<td><input type='text' name='remark[]' class='form-control' style='margin:10px; left:3px; width:90%;'></td>"
    +"<td><input type='text' name='attachment[]' class='form-control' style='margin:10px; left:3px; width:90%;'></td>"
    +"</tr>";
$('#lastcol').append(html);
}
```

here my php code :

```
$activity = $_POST['activity'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$remark = $_POST['remark'];
$attachment = $_POST['attachment'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$countcheck = count($value);
$countcheck2 = count($activity);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM checklist where apps_id = '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$countcheck3 = mysqli_num_rows($query);

for($y=0; $y < $countcheck2; $y++){
  $countcheck3 = $countcheck3 + 1;
  mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO checklist (apps_id, id, name) values ('$id','$countcheck3','$activity[$y]') WHERE apps_id = '$id'");
}

for($x=0;$x < $countcheck;$x++){
mysqli_query($db, "update maintenance_detail set value  = '$value[$x]'
                    WHERE maintenance_detail_id = '$id' and checklist_id = '$x'"); 
mysqli_query($db, "update maintenance_detail set remark = '$remark[$x]'
                    WHERE maintenance_detail_id = '$id' and checklist_id = '$x'"); 
mysqli_query($db, "update maintenance_detail set attachment = '$attachment[$x]'
                    WHERE maintenance_detail_id = '$id' and checklist_id = '$x'"); 
mysqli_query($db, "update maintenance_detail set status = '$status[$x]'
                    WHERE maintenance_detail_id = '$id' and checklist_id = '$x'");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use JavaScript to save values to you database? not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I've made this task in my case with additional function to set uniq key. In my case I have to add flight segments and direction so I have non index template which getting calculated dynamically indexes.